# Could you identify which species of ant is this queen?

Tags: species-identification

could you identify which species of ant is this queen. I caught it in Bangalore, India. I caught it after a rain at around five to six.

[image: ][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbTIF.jpg)

Comment: You should probably add more information, such as the time and place where it was caught (including ecological context).

Comment: I caught it at around five to six. I also caught it directly after a rain storm. I live in a relatively warm place which is not to humid. Oh and I caught it just outside my house.

Comment: Oh I also caught it in Bangalore, India which is where I live.

Comment: @DarkGuardian2006 please [edit] your question to add the details. Do not reply in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Although absolutely no formal criteria are visible on your photo, the general shape of the ant, especially the wide elongated head and low thorax, is typical of the ant genus Camponotus.

See ref below:

> Bolton, B., Alpert, G., Ward, P. S., & Naskrecki, P. (2006). Bolton’s
>   Catalogue of Ants of the World. Massachusetts, Harvard University
>   Press (CD-ROM).